# Accessing a function call that is within grouping operators

Tags: javascript

I have the following line of code:

```
(function f() {});
```

Is there a way we can reference f() outside of the grouping?

Comment: What excatly is the Problem? Can you provide some more Context?

Comment: If you want to be able to access it, why not define it another way? Like ´(window.f = function(){})´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esailija's answer is innovative but it misses the point. For example if you're using the function expression as follows then using `.prototype.constructor` makes no sense:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (function f() {}), false);
```

In such a case I prefer making the function expression a function declaration instead and replacing the expression with the function name:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (f), false);

function f() {}
```

The above program is perfectly valid. You can call a function declaration before it appears in the program. Now you can reference `f` "outside of its grouping". It's kind of like cheating but then again this is the way people normally do it (minus the unnecessary parentheses).

Comment: out of curiosity, why the parens around f in the AEL call?

Comment: @dandavis For fun. The question asked whether there's a way to reference `f` "outside of the grouping". If I'd not put the parentheses around `f` in the `addEventListener` call then it wouldn't be "inside the grouping" in the first place would it? :P

Answer (score 2):

`(function f() {}).prototype.constructor`

Answer (score 2):

thank's to javascript's leaky assignments, you can always just get the value of (almost) any expression:

```
 (function f() {}).valueOf() // == function f() {}
```

Comment: `valueOf()` is a normal method call that just happens to be defined for functions in a way that returns the function itself. It does not "get the value of any expression"

Comment: it gets the value of the result of the expression, hence its name, as long as the result has valueOf (null and undefined don't). ex: (3*5).valueOf()==15, ( !0 ).valueOf()==true, etc...